# Rotation about the Y-Axis

Tags: math, matlab, linear-algebra

Doing a couple rotations in Matlab, one which is rotation about the y-axis, however online I've found two different answers: [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/matrix/orthogonal/rotation/index.htm) and [here](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm). Which is correct, if both how does one get to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two answers you link to are the same, up to different notation. The angle q in one link corresponds to the angle -a in the other, and since

```
sin(-q) = -sin(q)
```

for any `q`, we have that

```
sin(a) = -sin(q)
```

which introduces the difference in sign. The siggraph link also has a 4-dimensional matrix, which allows for translations, but the last row and column of this can be ignored if you want a pure rotation.

Comment: More generally, they are transposed

Comment: Yup. Since rotation matrices are orthogonal, the matrix inverse is equal to the transpose. As rotation about of angle -q is the inverse operation of rotation of q (about the same axis), the change of sign of the rotation angle will always produce the matrix transpose, for any axis of rotation.